# Get records from json store extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, store

I have a json store loaded, I need to grab one record from it.
I used : `getAt(index)`, `find()`, `getById()`, but no results .
This is my code :

```
var appSettingReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({     
                root: 'results',
              },[
                {name: 'id', type: 'int', mapping: 'id'},
                {name: 'projetId', type: 'int', mapping: 'projetId'},
                {name: 'resLevels', type: 'int', mapping: 'resLevels'},
                {name: 'maxResToLock',  type: 'int', mapping: 'maxResToLock'},
                {name: 'maxTimeToLock', type: 'int', mapping: 'maxTimeToLock'},
                {name: 'infosToPrint', type: 'string', mapping: 'infosToPrint'}
              ])

var appSettingStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                        url: 'inc/getSettings.php',
                        method: 'POST'
                    }),
                baseParams:{task: "app"}, 
                reader : appSettingReader,
                sortInfo:{field: 'id', direction: "DESC"}
               })

appSettingStore.load();
```

This code return undefined :

```
console.log(appSettingStore.getAt(0));

console.log(appSettingStore.find("id","1"));
```

This is the json string returned from server :

```
{success:true,"results":[{"id":"1","projetId":"1","resLevels":"1","maxResToLock":"40","maxTimeToLock":"10","infosToPrint":"1_2_3_5","hotlineMail":"admin@app.com"}]}
```

I've also tested this code :

```
var records = new Array()       
var test = appSettingStore.each(function(rec){
            records.push(rec)
         })
console.log(records)
```

and I get an empty array !

PS : This store is not bound to any component; 
I just want to read and write to it.

Comment: I noticed one problem that you'll have. In your JsonReader's fields object you declare a field called "idProjet", but your server returns "projetId".  Make sure those match to get desired results.

Comment: it was a mistake the issue not resolved , i get the store fine loaded i've tested with a grid it work ! i still cant use find() or any filter function

Comment: What was the problem, out of curiosity?

Comment: the problem is that the store loads fine , but i can not use methods like : find() , getById() , getAt() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place a callback on the store, that will be fired after it loads. You can then use the data as required.

```
store.load({
    callback : function(r, options, success) {
        console.log(r.data)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the server is returning invalid JSON.  Why does your server-side script's output start with "("?

If that's not actually the problem, maybe you should consider accepting some more answers to your questions.  People will be more likely to help.

**EDIT**: Okay, so you're pretty sure you're getting valid json back from the server.  Try adding a 'success' property to your server's output.

If that doesn't work, you'll want to dig in a little more.  Try adding a callback option to your store's .load(), and look at the stuff that gets passed into the callback.  That should help you figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: no its not that the problème , thank you iam waiting for more answers

Comment: there is no issue in the stor it load fine , i can bind it with a grid i dont know where is the probleme , i cant use store methodes to find records